# Why does Scala Cats use typeclasses instead of inheritance?

Tags: scala, inheritance, functional-programming, typeclass, scala-cats

#### What's the point of using a typeclass over inheritance?

This is a function that uses the `Monad` typeclass by a context bound:

```
def f[A : Monad](x:A) = ???
```

( Yeah, we get flatMap method now)

This, however, uses inheritance with a subtype bound:

```
def f[A <: Monad](x:A) = ???  
f(x) // where x is a CatsList which implements Monad trait.
```

( We also get flatMap method now.)

Don't both achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typeclasses are more flexible. In particular, it's possible to retrofit a typeclass to an existing type easily. To do this with inheritance, you would need to use the adapter pattern, which can get cumbersome when you have multiple traits.

For example, suppose you had two libraries which added the traits `Measurable` and `Functor`, respectively, using inheritance:

```
trait Measurable {
  def length: Int
}

trait Functor[A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Functor[B]
}
```

The first library helpfully defined an adapter for List => Measurable:

```
class ListIsMeasurable(ls: List[_]) extends Measurable {
  def length = ls.length
}
```

And the second library did the same for List => Functor. Now we want to write a function that takes things that have both length and map methods:

```
def foo(x: Measurable with Functor) = ???
```

Of course, we should hope to be able to pass it a `List`. However, our adapters are useless here, and we have to write yet another adapter to make `List` conform to `Measurable with Functor`. In general, if you have `n` interfaces that might apply to `List`, you have `2^n` possible adapters. On the other hand, if we had used typeclasses, there would have been no need for the extra boilerplate of a third typeclass instance:

```
def foo[A : Measurable : Functor](a: A) = ???
```

Comment: Did you mean such case: for multiple typeclass, we can do [T : Monoid : Monad] whereas multiple adapters can not be composed to satisfy [T <: Monoid with Monad] ?

Comment: @WeiChingLin Exactly. I've added an example. Luka's answer also gives some good reasons why typeclasses are more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

What you're saying is possible for the simplest cases, but type classes can give you much better flexibility in a lot of cases.

Take for example the `Monoid` type class:

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  def empty: A
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}
```

If you try to express the `empty` function with inheritance, you'll see it is pretty much impossible. That is because type classes operate on types rather than individual class instances.

Now let's define a `Monoid` for something like `Tuple2`:

```
implicit def tupleMonoid[A: Monoid, B: Monoid]: Monoid[(A, B)] = ...
```

Now you're in a territory where inheritance can't get you anywhere at all. With type classes we can add conditions to type class instances. I.e. a Tuple is a `Monoid`, when both of its types are also `Monoid`s. With inheritance you can't do this.